# Getting these warning Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TakingInput {
    public static void main (String []args){

        Scanner number1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner number2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number1: ");
        int x = number1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number2: ");
        int y = number2.nextInt();
        
        int z = y+x;

        System.out.println("the sum is : " + z);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your input format so we can take a look.

Comment: Please provide some example input and the stack trace of the `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: This works fine for me. What was your input? It should be two integers, each followed by a return.

Comment: @NomadMaker it most certainly weren't integers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No need to create Scanner object for each input. Just create one object and use it to get user input.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number1: ");
int x = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter number2: ");
int y = sc.nextInt();
```

Read online articles on Java before moving to coding part.